# What oauth pattern to follow for a super user assuming the identity of a customer

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I'm working at a company where we have a standard JWT token given to an end user. This user will get their JWT access token by going through the authorisation code oauth flow.  By passing their access token into the Authorization header they can make calls into the microservice api's.

We now have a scenario where we need someone from the customer service centre assume the identity of an end user for the purpose of giving the service centre representative access to the users data for short period of time.

To solve this we have discussed having two access tokens flowing into the Authorization header in the microservice api's. The first would represent the customer service centre representative and the second would be the users access token but i am confused on how to best architect this solution.

Can anyone recommend a good solution staying as close to open id connect standards as possible. Microsoft seem to have an oauth flow named `on behalf of` which kind of matches what i want but seems more like it caters for a system `on behalf of` a user where I want a user `on behalf of` another user.

thanks

Comment: Please let me why do you want the customer service center representative token in the auth service? if there is any use case pls let me know

Answer (score 0):

**LONGER TERM**

[User Managed Access](https://www.forgerock.com/privacy/user-managed-access) may provide solutions in this area:

- End User sets a policy at the Authorization Server for their personal resources
- A Company Administrator applies a policy at the Authorization Server for corporate resources (for multiple users)
- A Requesting Party (app) presents claims as proof that they meet the policy

**REAL WORLD**

Almost no Authorization Servers support this capability, and even those that do may not do what you want. It is more than an OAuth pattern though, since a solution also ties into back end behaviour.

**WHAT I WOULD DO**

Build a solution around claims:

- Service centre user logs in, to establish their own identity
- After login, lookup claims, to see if the user has 'super' rights
- If so, your UI presents an option to act on behalf of another user
- Service center user types in email of who they are acting as
- Update claims with the second identity
- Authorization needs to take both identities into account
- Auditing needs to log both identities

The above list hints at requirements, and of course not all of these can be solved with OAuth, but claims should give you the flexibility you need.

See [my claims write up](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/) for how you could apply this pattern to collect claims from multiple places - not just access tokens. In your case, the ApiClaims object could include your database user ids for both users.